# What's the best way to access data in another Qt widget for the purpose of filtering?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

#### Situation

I made a custom drop-down widget (`CompanyDropDown`) to retrieve names of companies stored in the database. It works similar to `QLineEdit`, with the difference being it shows a list of a company names upon typing. When a company name is selected, it emits a signal `companyChanged` with the company id.

Right below it, there is a `QTabWidget` that splits the information of a selected company across different tabs, each of which having a different widget. Let's say I have three of such widgets: `W1`, `W2`, and `W3`.

`W1`, for example, has two child widgets for the purpose of filtering, `FilterA` and `FilterB`, a button `Apply`, and a `QTableView`. The `QTableView` has as its model a subclass of `QAbstractTableModel`. When `Apply` is clicked, data on the filtering widgets is passed onto a method of that model, which queries company data from the database. Finally, information is shown on the table.

A `MainWidget` encloses `CompanyDropDown` and `QTabWidget`, and provides the bridge between them by connecting `CompanyDropDown.companyChanged` to `W1`, `W2`, and `W3`. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMNlM.png) is a picture illustrating the window layout.

#### Question

When a company name is selected on `CompanyDropDown`, the company id is simply forwarded to other widgets and the filtering is applied. The code is something like this:

```py
class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.w1 = W1()
        self.w2 = W2()
        self.w3 = W3()

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.w1, 'W1')
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.w2, 'W2')
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.w3, 'W3')

        self.companyDropDown = CompanyDropDown()
        self.companyDropDown.companyChanged.connect(self.w1.onCompanyChanged)
        self.companyDropDown.companyChanged.connect(self.w2.onCompanyChanged)
        self.companyDropDown.companyChanged.connect(self.w3.onCompanyChanged)

        ... # layout definitions

class W1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filterA = FilterA()
        self.filterB = FilterB()

        self.apply = QPushButton('Apply')
        self.apply.clicked.connect(self.applyFilter)

        self.tableView = QTableView()
        self.tableView.setModel(MyCustomTableModel())

        ... # layout definitions

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def onCompanyChanged(self, companyId: int):
        a = self.filterA.data()
        b = self.filterB.data()

        self.tableView.model().populate(companyId, a, b)

    def applyFilter(self):
        ...

def MyCustomTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def populate(self, companyId: int, a: Any, b: Any):
        ...
```

That's good. The problem is what I should do on `applyFilter()` when only filtering data changes on `FilterA` or `FilterB`, since I don't have access to the company id. Here's the code illustrating the problem:

```py
class W1(QWidget):
    def applyFilter(self):
        companyId = ... # where from?
        a = self.filterA.data()
        b = self.filterB.data()

        self.tableView.model().populate(companyId, a, b)
```

Well, one obvious solution is to store the company id into `W1` and reset it every time `onCompanyChanged` is called, but that means I would have to the same to `W2` and `W3` as well, as they are similar widgets to `W1`. This doesn't seem cleanest to me. I don't like the idea of storing the company id around in many widgets when it may well be provided by `CompanyDropDown` itself. It would be best if `W1` could access the company id directly from a method, say, `CompanyDropDown.companyId()` in the same way it does to `FilterA.data()` and `FilterB.data()`. What would be the best practice in my situation?

#### Edit

As I said in a comment, one idea I had is to delegate the call to `populate()` to `MainWidget`:

```py
class W1(QWidget):
    filterA_Changed = pyqtSignal(...)
    filterB_Changed = pyqtSignal(...)

    def model(self) -> MyCustomTableModel:
        return self.tableView.model()

    def a(self):
        return self.filterA.data()

    def b(self):
        return self.filterB.data()

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.w1.filterA_Changed.connect(self.onW1FilterAChanged)
        self.w1.filterB_Changed.connect(self.onW1FilterBChanged)

    def onW1FilterAChanged(self, a: Any):
        b     = self.w1.b()
        model = self.w1.model()
        model.populate(self.companyDropDown.companyId(), a, b)

    def onW1FilterBChanged(self, b: Any):
        a     = self.w1.a()
        model = self.w1.model()
        model.populate(self.companyDropDown.companyId(), a, b)
```

Comment: Does the behavior of `onCompanyChanged` change between the different W classes? If it doesn't, then it means that you're practically using the same model for them, meaning that you could just populate a *single* model on the main window and then just do `setModel()`. Note that there's nothing wrong in storing the id as an instance attribute. Also consider using QSortFilterProxyModel.

Comment: The behavior of `onCompanyChanged` differs between classes because each of them has their own filtering widgets. The model class also differs. I gave the example of `MyCustomTableModel`, but there is one model class for each W class. The reason for that is I'm using SQLAlchemy and each subclass of `QAbstractTableModel` deals with a different ORM-mapped class. The idea behind the W classes is that each of them present company data that lies in a different SQL table.

Comment: Then just store the id as an instance attribute. While querying the parent is an option, it wouldn't change that much with this type of structure, and child objects should normally only act on themselves without relying on the object hierarchy "above" them. Alternatively (but that won't change that much, conceptually), implement the model in a way that *it* stores the company id.

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently, storing the company id as an instance attribute. I thought of storing it the on the model, but the thing is that both the widget and the model classes don't make sense to. They only use it on a call to `populate()`. A third alternative is to pass the instance of `CompanyDropDown` to W classes, but that smells. The problem with my structure is that the widget that provides filtering data is outside of the class that's doing the filtering, as I want to "share" it between W classes.

Comment: Passing the widget won't change a lot. Just store the value in the "nearest" common object (which would probably be W). There could be other solutions, but since the code you provided is too abstract, it's impossible to provide further suggestions. Btw, note that on StackOverflow we normally don't answer questions asking "what's better for my program", as they are too specific to a single user case, and only you can know what's best for *your* program. If it works and makes sense, it's probably fine, but we cannot answer about the implementation of a specific program.

Comment: I see. I said "best way" because I thought there should be a correct way of doing it. Another solution I just thought of is to define signals on the W classes to notify changes on the filtering widgets, and provide access to the model instance. For example, the `W1` class would emit two signals, `filterA_Changed` and `filterB_Changed`, and define a method `model()`. These signals would be captured by `MainWidget`, which has direct access to `CompanyDropDown`, and would be used along with `W1.model()` to populate the model. Do you think this would be better than storing id as attributes?

Comment: I updated the post to better illustrate my idea

Comment: As said, there is no "correct" way to do so. There are many possible approaches, some are better or worse than others, but in the end only you can know what better suits *your* needs, in terms of project structure, object hierarchy, code maintenance and even "mental" organization. Knowing more about your program and reading its current code, one may provide some suggestions about it, but this would just help *your very specific* case, and this is not the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your input anyway :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you just assign mainwindow and the parent to each of the `'W1'`, `'W2'`.... and access the dropdown through self.parent().companyDropDown?